# Nginx rewrite rule to remove path node

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Let's say a user tries to access a given image on my website using the following url:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/image1.jpg?someParam=100`

i need a rewrite rule to this, removing the 'blog' node from the path:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/image1.jpg?someParam=100`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this one:

```
location /blog {
 rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

If you need this for more than one site you can't just put it higher in hierarchy because "location" clause can't be specified globally, only for specific site. If you need to add this clause for two sites or more you can put it another config file and then just "include" it in each site that needs this redirection.

Comment: This works for in the same server. How to make it work for the different domain?

Comment: Just include the new domain as part of the rewrite:

    `rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ https://blog.example.com$1 permanent;`

Answer (score 2):

Depending where you define the `rewrite` directive you have two ways to implement it:

#### A. In the `server` context

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 last;
    return 403;
    ...
}
```

#### B. In the `location` context

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

**Teo, why did you change the flag to `break`?*** Because, if this directive is put inside of a `location` context, the `last` flag might make `nginx` to run 10 cycles and return the 500 error.